# facebook chat in silverlight

Tags: asp.net, wcf, silverlight, facebook, wcf-binding

I have a silverlight application and i want is that my application should ask for the user name and password and the client should be able to start chat with their facebook friends.Could this be done? and if so then is there sample code available

Answer (score 1):

This is the question of what kind of API Facebook provides. There aren't any inherent issues here if Facebook exposes this sort of functionality to third parties. I'm not an expert in this, but reading the facebook documentation should help you out.

http://developers.facebook.com

Also maybe check out these links:

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/LiveMessage.send

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:chat-invite

It looks like some folks developed a framework to more easily interop facebook with .net based technologies:

http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/

Here they are discussing the LiveMessage stuff:

http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=62384

People did facebook chat clones on the web, and in standalone apps (http://www.faceoffim.com/), so at least in principle it's certainly doable.